# How to get Launch time of instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to get infromation of aws instance which are running or stopped with their launched_at time. I tried this:

```
@resp = client.describe_instance_status({
  filters: [
    {  
      name: "instance-state-name",
      values: ["stopped","running"],
    },
  ],
  instance_ids: aws_instance_ids,  # this is array of aws instance ids
  dry_run: false,
  include_all_instances: true,
})
```

This api call give me this output in response.

```
<struct Aws::EC2::Types::InstanceStatus availability_zone="us-east-1b", events=[], instance_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXX", instance_state=<struct Aws::EC2::Types::InstanceState code=80, name="stopped">, instance_status=# <struct Aws::EC2::Types::InstanceStatusSummary details=[], status="not-applicable">, system_status=<struct Aws::EC2::Types::InstanceStatusSummary details=[], status="not-applicable">>
```

but i don't get launched_at instance information. How can i get it with this API call?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable method for getting the Launch time of an instance that is stopped. (Besides -- it might have many of them!)

Instead, use [AWS Config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/), which can provide a full history of activity with resources including when it was started, stopped and modified.

Comment: thanks @John Rotenstein. please tell me , why events array blank here in response , i am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is it blank for all instances, or only stopped instances?

Comment: it's blank for all instances.

Comment: @NeerajAmoli events are scheduled maintenance events for the instance, for things like power maintenance, hypervisor upgrades, and hardware retirement. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein OP is using DescribeInstanceStatus rather than DescribeInstances... which provides a `launchTime`... isn't that what we want?

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbo is there any alternate method to achieve this issue ?

Comment: I generally use `DescribeInstances` and look at the ENI attach time since people rarely change the ENI.

Comment: thanks  everyone. i just change method and it work for me. 
    
       @resp = client.describe_instances({
           filters: [
          {
            name: "instance-state-name",
            values: ["stopped","running"],
          },
         ],
         instance_ids: aws_instance_ids,
         dry_run: false,
        })

Answer (score 0):

```
     @resp = client.describe_instances({ 
     filters: [ 
       {
          name: "instance-state-name", 
          values: ["stopped","running"], 
        }, 
      ], 
     instance_ids: aws_instance_ids, #we pass here array of ec2 instance id
     dry_run: false, })
```

this api call fetched  launched time details or all details of ec2 instances

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what this code is doing and how it answers the question.